# inserting image to sqlite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans, blob

I'm creating application using sqlite database and netbeans .I have a problem when I save an image to data base.
I have an image field in database which data type is BLOB and i'm inserting a byte array . i know it doesn't match.but when i save it holds value like this  "[B@2c8f544b" but actual values should be like this  "BLOB (Size: 1850)". if there is some value like that then only i can retrieve the image. I really can't figure out how to do this.if you have any reference  please let me know.

my idea is before save to database convert byte array to BLOB type.but I couldn't find any code.

```
        String fname = p.fname;
        String lname = p.lname;
        byte[] image = p.image_det;
        String mob = p.mobile;
        String wor = p.work;
        String hom = p.home;
        String fax = p.fax;
        int pID ;

        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(pID) FROM person");

        pID =    Integer.parseInt(rst.getString(1))+1;


        Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
        stmt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person(pID,F_name,L_name,image) VALUES ("+pID+" ,'"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+image+"' ) ");
```

//-------------------------getting image path and  get image data to array called image_details

```
    File f;
    String ipath = f.getAbsolutePath();  // getting image path
    byte[] image_detail = null;

    try 
    {
        File image = new File(ipath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image); 


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        for(int readNum;(readNum = fis.read(buf))!= -1;)
        {
            baos.write(buf, 0,readNum);
        }

        image_detail =  baos.toByteArray();

        per.setImage_det(image_detail); // set image data for person class
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? May be this helps http://mornie.org/blog/2007/01/10/Storing-binary-data-in-SQLite/

Comment: You need to use a "prepared statement" with the blob data being "bound" to the statement before execution.

Comment: It worked .. thank you very much @HotLicks .if you don't mind can you explain me the mistake .

Comment: If you try to use a pasted-together INSERT rather than the prepared statement you end up pasting in gobbledygook for the blob data -- it won't convert to characters nicely, and there will undoubtedly be bit patterns (eg, quotes, parens, etc) that confuse the SQL statement parser.  Using a prepared statement the blob data isn't interpreted as characters.